Postgres sql to compare data between two tables and populate in target
Scenario :
Input table 1 : need to compare the value of field2 of table1 with field 3 of table 2
example :
select from svc_lz.fn_abc;svc_lz.fn_cde; so field 2 values of table 1 is
present after 'select' i.e svc_lz.fn_abc and svc_lz.fn_cde so we need to
join with field 3 of table 2 example : svc_lz.fn_abc and svc_lz.fn_cde.If there is join
then fetch field 4  assigned to table 2 and place it in output table field 3.
Input table 1:



field1
field2




a
select from svc_lz.fn_abc;svc_lz.fn_cde;


b
select *From mfg_lz.fn_test,mfg_a.fn_test1


c
select *From mfg_j.fn_test2


d
select *From mfg_j.fn_test3;mfg_j.fn_test4;


e
select *From mfg_j.fn_test5(100);mfg_j.fn_test6(1000)


f
select *From mfg_j.fn_test5_abc(100);mfg_j.fn_test6_abc(1000)



Input table 2 :



field3
field4




svc_lz.fn_abc
{test}


svc_lz.fn_cde
{test1,test2}


mfg_lz.fn_test
{test3}


mfg_j.fn_test4
{test5}


mfg_j.fn_test5
{}


mfg_j.fn_test6
{test7}



Output:



field1
field2
field3




a
select from



svc_lz.fn_abc;svc_lz.fn_cde;
test,test1,test2



b
select *From mfg_lz.fn_test,mfg_a.fn_test1
test3


c
select *From mfg_j.fn_test2
NULL


d
select *From mfg_j.fn_test3;mfg_j.fn_test4;
test5


e
select *From mfg_j.fn_test5(100);mfg_j.fn_test6(1000)
test7


f
select *From



mfg_j.fn_test5_abc(100);mfg_j.fn_test6_abc(1000)
NULL




I have search and check need to do string_split and perform inner join between field 2 from tbl1 and
field3 from tbl2 but I am not sure how to start with,I have tried using cte
functionality but I am new to sql so struggling to find the starting point for this.If
anyone can help pls.

See example
select field1,field2,string_agg(distinct fld,',') field3
from(
select *
from(
select field1,field2,fld
from table1 t1
left join (
    select * from table2
    cross join 
       string_to_table(trim(replace(replace(field4,'{',''),'}','')),',') fld
  )t2
  -- on t1.field2 like concat('%',t2.field3,'%')
  -- more complicated search with regexp
  on concat(t1.field2,';') similar to concat('%',t2.field3,'[();,]%'))x
)b
group by field1,field2

Result is



field1
field2
field3




a
select from svc_lz.fn_abc;svc_lz.fn_cde;
test,test1,test2


b
select *From mfg_lz.fn_test,mfg_a.fn_test1
test3


c
select *From mfg_j.fn_test2
null


d
select *From mfg_j.fn_test3;mfg_j.fn_test4;
test5



First part is
select * from table2
cross join string_to_table(trim(replace(replace(field4,'{',''),'}','')),',') fld

This subquery output is



field3
field4
fld




svc_lz.fn_abc
{test}
test


svc_lz.fn_cde
{test1,test2}
test1


svc_lz.fn_cde
{test1,test2}
test2


mfg_lz.fn_test
{test3}
test3


mfg_j.fn_test4
{test5}
test5



Next step JOIN table1 and expanded table2 (previous subquery)
select field1,field2,fld
from table1 t1
left join (
    select * from table2
    cross join 
       string_to_table(trim(replace(replace(field4,'{',''),'}','')),',') fld
  )t2
  -- on t1.field2 like concat('%',t2.field3,'%')
  -- more complicated search with regexp
  on concat(t1.field2,';') similar to concat('%',t2.field3,'[();,]%'))x

Output is



field1
field2
fld




a
select from svc_lz.fn_abc;svc_lz.fn_cde;
test


a
select from svc_lz.fn_abc;svc_lz.fn_cde;
test1


a
select from svc_lz.fn_abc;svc_lz.fn_cde;
test2


b
select *From mfg_lz.fn_test,mfg_a.fn_test1
test3


c
select *From mfg_j.fn_test2
null


d
select *From mfg_j.fn_test3;mfg_j.fn_test4;
test5



Demo and here

Thank you @ValNik-One more scenario that I have here is in few cases we have field2 as select from svc_lz.fn_abc(100);svc_lz.fn_cde(200); Can you pls help

Update data example with this cases. What is and what you want get.

This is nothing to change query. See (https://dbfiddle.uk/2zLBcFoG).

@ValNik- for most of the cases it is giving me correct result but there is a case where its giving false positive. Example in input 1,I have added row f. dbfiddle.uk/oqsEZS0q.For this scenario its not giving exact match.Hence I was expecting it to populate null.

Yes, I see. More strict comparison is needed.

Try on concat(t1.field2,';') similar to concat('%',t2.field3,'[();,]%') Example (https://dbfiddle.uk/H--yq0M6)

Thank you ValNik for your help.I will let you know after doing end to end testing.

@ValNik-In some cases ,I am getting duplicate values for fld and str_agg is getting duplicate values for those...Is there any way to keep 1 value.Example : getting data like test3,test3 however I was expecting only test3 after string_agg.

Distinct fld do not produce 2 equal values in aggregated string. There some other reason.
